# TransactionScope в цикле

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

Допустим, код имеет такую структуру:

```
using (var tran = new TransactionScope())
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach (var val in col)
    {
        i++;
        if (i == 10)
        {
            i = 0;
            tran.Complete();
        }
        //Какие-то действия с бд
    }
}
```

На msdn говорится, что `Complete` может быть вызван 1 раз. Можно ли что-нибудь придумать, что бы, используя 1 `TransactionScope` выполнять несколько коммитов.

Иными словами я хочу, что бы каждые 10 итераций цикла были как 1 транзакция.

Answer (score 2):

Если вы внимательно прочитаете [MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.transactions.transactionscope.complete?view=net-5.0), то увидите, что реальный коммит (или откат) транзакции происходит не в методе `Complete()`, а при вызове `Dispose()` -- т.е. в конце блока `using`. Поэтому как ни крутите, а выход один -- создавать свой скоуп на каждые 10 итераций.

Чтобы несколько упростить код, можно воспользоваться методом [Batch()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15414347/how-to-loop-through-ienumerable-in-batches/15414467#15414467) (еще один вариант реализации -- [тут](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/plinq-and-int32-maxvalue/)), а каждую пачку обрабатывать в своем скоупе. Выглядеть будет примерно так:

```
foreach (var batch in col.Batch(10))
{
    using (var tran = new TransactionScope())
    {
        foreach (var val in batch)
        {
            //Какие-то действия с бд
        }
        tran.Complete();
    }
}
```